# Using ajax with mysql to validate before rendering

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, pdo

i am pretty new to ajax but what i might ask might be simple for some of you.

I am looking for a best way to check that what a user is posting to my `checkdata.php` is verily to the `price` in the database.

I have a very long database which works find but I need to do this validation.

product

```
pid      name                  size     price  
1        chocolate              12        30.00
```

I have a form and in my form I am posting `pid` `name` and `size`

In my PDO statement I am doing this

```
SELECT pid, price, name, size from Product WHERE pid=:pid AND size=:size AND name=:name
```

This works fine.

But I want to use ajax to check that what the user is the same as whats in the database and its equal to the same price in the database.

If everything is not the same then it should have an alert message saying "don't mess with the code."

I have a very long table. sorry I cant show the code it too long

in the table i have name which i echo from the database

`size` is a dropdown list

and `pid` is an hidden input.

I currently have this jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#selected').hide();
    $('#button').click(function(){
        var pid = $('#pid').val();
        var size = $('#size').val();
        var Qty = $('#Qty').val();
        var price = '\u00A3' + parseInt($('#pricetag').text().replace(/^\D/, ''), 10) * Qty;
        var size = $('#size').val();
        if (!/^[1-9]\d?$/.test(Qty)){
            alert('Quantity should not be below 1 or null');
            return false; // don't continue
        } 
        else {
        $('#sprice').text(price);
        $('#ssize').text(size);
        $('#selected').slideDown();
        }
        $.ajax({
            url: 'checkdata.php',
            type: 'POST',
            data: { pid:pid, size:size, Qty:Qty},
            success: function(data)
            {

            }
        });
    });
});

<?php
session_start()

if(isset($_POST['pid']) && isset($_POST['size']) && isset($_POST['Qty']) && isset($_POST['name'])){   
    $pid = $_POST['pid'];
    $size = $_POST["size"];
    $qty = $_POST['Qty'];
    $name= $_POST['name'];

.
.
.

 somewhere in the php tag I have a statement to get the right price based on what data is getting posted
   SELECT pid, price, name, size from Product WHERE pid=:pid AND size=:size AND name=:name

?>
```

**Summary**
How can i use ajax to check that what is getting posted is the same as it is on the database before I render the page.

Comment: Why do you need to re-check the price? If the user picks a size and quantity you should only pass the pid, size, and qty and when processing this you will pull the price from your database and not a passed variable.

Comment: @ChristopherMorrissey I am posting `pid, size, and qty` then i am using it to find the price but the issue I am facing is that if some idiot change the value of the size. in the cart it will still render the page but they will be nothing in it. I thought by checking the price before rendering the page I will be able to stop this from happening

Comment: @yourcommonsense no point disliking the question, if you can't answer it

Comment: @ChristopherMorrissey I have updated the question if you are still looking to answer this question. Thanks

Comment: why would they be able to change the size of a product if that size is not available for that product ?

Comment: @ChristopherMorrissey the size is a dropdown list.... so the choose from the list. Lets  say someone wanted to be stupid and click the value using something like firebug or chrome inspect element or whatever and posted it... I want to be able to cross reference that what is getting posted is validate to what is in the database.

Comment: based on what you have I wouldn't worry about if some one is changing the code, if they submit a product that is invalid and it isn't added to the cart its not added to the cart that's fine ... they know why.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't be round-tripping the prices through the client anyways. It's one thing to pull up a price and display it to a user, but you should **NEVER** accept a price value BACK from the user. Always fetch a fresh copy from the database when it comes time to actually calculate costs.

If you want to "fix" the price so that if the item is in the shopping cart for a prolonged duration, and you're changing prices in the database, then keep the price in the user's session. That's a purely server-side data structure, and can't be meddled with directly.

That'd let you say things like "item price has changed since you added it to the cart. accept new updated price or remove from cart?".

Comment: i am not posting the price... as u see from the question I am only posting variables which I am using to find the price.

Comment: Then why the "don't mess with the code" stuff? Let the user meddle with the price in their browser all they want - your system should be utterly ignoring that hacked-up price

Comment: I am posting pid, size, and qty then i am using it to find the price but the issue I am facing is that if some idiot change the value of the size. in the cart it will still render the page but they will be nothing in it. I thought by checking the price before rendering the page I will be able to stop this from happening

Comment: i know i shouldnt be bothered if the wanna piss about with the code but it doesn't look nice if the page still renders and they is nothing inside

Comment: then you're doing something wrong. shopping cart data should be kept in a session. you may want to allow them to edit the cart, e.g. change quantities or add/remove items. but sizing and pricing information should only ever go server->client. If they're messing with the code ontheir client and break the quicky "display updated price now" javascript in the cart page, then they deserve to have their cart emptied.

Comment: you kinda get what I am saying but you don't. Try going on a shopping website and change the value of an idea then add to cart. 2 things might happen. 1) will be that you might get an error message 2) will be that what you added to cart will not show up in your shopping basket.

Comment: My question  relates to 2 things things.

Comment: I have updated the question from the `php` tag to show the select statement I have

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what your asking about.

Assume that if you're looking for validating the user discount coupon or etc, you may want to check the user Session in checkdata.php. Such as

```
$member_coupon=$_SESSION['MEMBER_COUPON'];

SELECT pid, name, size from Product where pid=:pid and coupon_id=$member_coupon
```

then

```
if(result){echo 'SUCCESS';}
else{ echo 'dont mess around';}
```

and ajax can use

```
success: function(results) { 
alert(results);
}
```

Comment: thanks for trying but your answer if off the topic and question I asked but this just semi gave me an idea. My question is how do I stop the checkdata page from rendering if someone change the value getting posted. The page render but its empty. I want to alert the use if what is getting posted doesn't match anything in the database